# @Hibernate org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I got this problem while editing list in Entity "SejourPerson", Plz can anyone helps me?

```
16:19:27.358 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - Deleting collection: [ma.neoxia.sejour.domain.entities.Hebergement.orderers#319]
16:19:27.358 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
16:19:27.358 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - delete from hebergements_ordonnateurs where id_hebergement=?
Hibernate: delete from hebergements_ordonnateurs where id_hebergement=?
16:19:27.358 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - done deleting collection
16:19:27.358 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Executing batch size: 1
16:19:27.358 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - Deleting rows of collection: [ma.neoxia.sejour.domain.entities.SejourPerson.hebergements#242]
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update hebergements set id_sejour_personne=null where id_sejour_personne=? and id=?
Hibernate: update hebergements set id_sejour_personne=null where id_sejour_personne=? and id=?
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - done deleting collection rows: 1 deleted
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - Inserting rows of collection: [ma.neoxia.sejour.domain.entities.SejourPerson.hebergements#242]
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister - done inserting rows: 0 inserted
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Executing batch size: 1
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
16:19:27.359 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - delete from hebergements where id=?
Hibernate: delete from hebergements where id=?
16:19:27.360 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Executing batch size: 1
16:19:27.366 [http-8080-1] ERROR org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - Exception executing batch: 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268) [hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268) [hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:189) [hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216) [hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383) [hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133) [hibernate-core-3.6.1.Final.jar:3.6.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656) [spring-orm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754) [spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) [spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393) [spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120) [spring-tx-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621) [spring-aop-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
    at ma.neoxia.sejour.services.impl.SejourPersonSerivceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1eeed1a4.edit(<generated>) [cglib-2.2.2.jar:na]
    at ma.neoxia.sejour.rest.RestSejourPerson.edit(RestSejourPerson.java:124) [ma.neoxia.sejour-0.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor750.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.5.Final.jar:na]
```

I am using Hibernate, I have table "SejourPerson" contains list of "hebergements" and this one contains list of "orderers" mapping in this way

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "sejours_personnes")
public class SejourPerson extends EntityObject implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private List<Hebergement> hebergements;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn( name = "id_sejour_personne")
    public List<Hebergement> getHebergements() {
        if(hebergements == null)
            hebergements = new ArrayList<Hebergement>();
        return hebergements;
    }

    public void setHebergements(List<Hebergement> hebergements) {
        this.hebergements = hebergements;
    }
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "hebergements")
public class Hebergement extends EntityObject implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    private Integer id;
    private List<Person> orderers;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "hebergements_ordonnateurs",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_hebergement",referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_personne_ordonateur",referencedColumnName="id_tier")})
    public List<Person> getOrderers() {
        if (orderers == null)
            orderers = new ArrayList<Person>();
        return orderers;
    }
}
```

I used flyway so in the script is like this:

```
--
-- Structure de la table `hebergements_ordonnateurs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hebergements_ordonnateurs` (
  `id_hebergement` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_personne_ordonateur` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_hebergement`,`id_personne_ordonateur`),
  KEY `id_hebergement` (`id_hebergement`),
  KEY `id_personne_ordonateur` (`id_personne_ordonateur`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Index pour la table `hebergements_ordonnateurs`
--

ALTER TABLE `hebergements_ordonnateurs`
    ADD INDEX(`id_hebergement`),
    ADD INDEX(`id_personne_ordonateur`);

ALTER TABLE `hebergements_ordonnateurs`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ho_hebergement` FOREIGN KEY (`id_hebergement`) REFERENCES `hebergements` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_ho_personne` FOREIGN KEY (`id_personne_ordonateur`) REFERENCES `personnes` (`id_tier`);
```

For the thransactional method, I edit the Object in this way

```
@Override
    public SejourPersonBean edit(SejourPersonBean bean) throws ReferentielServiceException {
        try {
            log.debug("Edit sejour person");
            SejourPerson sejourPerson = sejourPersonDao.findById(bean.getId());
            if (sejourPerson == null) {
                throw new ReferentielServiceException(ReferentielServiceExceptionCode.SEJOUR_PERSON_NOT_FOUND);
            }
            sejourPerson.getHebergements().clear();
            sejourPerson.getHebergements().addAll(HebergementBeanMapper.toEntities(bean.getHebergements()));

            sejourPersonDao.update(sejourPerson);
            SejourPerson objectToReturn = sejourPersonDao.findById(sejourPerson.getId());

            return SejourPersonBeanMapper.toBean(objectToReturn);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("SejourPersonServiceImpl: Error while editing sejour person " + e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new ReferentielServiceException(ReferentielServiceExceptionCode.ERROR_HAS_BEEN_THROWN);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the transactional method in which you perform the bulk update

Comment: @MaciejKowalski done

Comment: Exception says your hibernate entity is in stale state i.e. it is not in sync with the database which might have been updated from some other source. Before trying update just refresh entity. It will change the stale state and you will not see the exception then.

Comment: @VijendraKulhade thanks for ur reply, is it "SejourPerson" or "Hebergement" Entity ?? I do find "SejourPerson" by id before updating it ??

Comment: As `SejourPerson` has `Hebergement` entity so only refreshing `SejourPerson` should solve the problem.

Comment: In sejourPersonDao you can do refresh like this `this.getHibernateTemplate().refresh(sejourPerson);`

Comment: it doesn't work, i can't call this.getHibernateTemplate() @VijendraKulhade

Comment: what is your hibernate version?

Comment: @VijendraKulhade I have 3.6.1.Final